# In Vim/Vi, how do you move the cursor to the end of the previous word?

Tags: vim, vi

In Vim's normal mode:

- <kbd>e</kbd> goes to the end of the next word
- <kbd>w</kbd> goes to the beginning of the next word
- <kbd>b</kbd> goes to the beginning of the previous word

How do you move the cursor to the *end* of the *previous* word?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not a single key... but <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> is what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: For people like me wondering the difference between `ge` and `be`, it's that you can be in the middle of the word and you'll go to the end of the previous, while `be` you need to be on the first char of the initial word.

Comment: And `gE` for the end of the previous `WORD`. :)

Comment: seriously why isn't there a single key shortcut for this by default? this looks like something people would be using as frequently as `w`. am I missing something? (I know it can be mapped, just curious why)

Comment: While `be` is convenient, it's a combination of two commands, so you can't use it like: `d` `be`. Whereas `d` `ge` does work

Answer (score 61):

Try <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>:

```
ge                      Backward to the end of word [count] |inclusive|.

                                                        *gE*
gE                      Backward to the end of WORD [count] |inclusive|.
```

Comment: The difference between `word` and `WORD`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931032/vim-word-vs-word

Answer (score 35):

as seen on VIM manual (section 03.1), you can use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to go to the end of previous word

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to do these to go to the space preceding a word (one character after <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>: (both are only 2 keys)

1. <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> will take you to the space after the previous word
2. <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> will also do that, in most cases.

The exception is when you are at the beginning of a line, in which case

3. <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> does something similar, in 3 keypresses