# How to select words from inside current word and backwards in vim

Tags: vim

I've had some fun learning vim, but have encountered a problem. While it's fairly straightforward to select from inside the current word and forward (`v` + `iw` + `w` +`w` + ...), and backwards (`v` + `b` + `b` + ... or `v` + `ge` + `ge` + ...). (This question describes that process quite well: [In Vim/Vi, how do you move the cursor to the end of the previous word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125270/in-vim-vi-how-do-you-move-the-cursor-to-the-end-of-the-previous-word) ). I know one solution is to move the marker to the end of the word before beginning the selection, but it seems less elegant than just including the entire word the cursor is in in the selection (like you can with `iw` when going forward (I think what I'm asking for is a sort of `ib` or modifier key to make `w` cycle backwards without making custom aliases)).

Is it possible or am I just being unreasonable? Sorry for the messy formatting.

Comment: can you make some example, to show us, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: With custom mappings, everything is possible; but I so far haven't actually seen the need for backward selection. Sorry, but this looks like theoretical musings, not an actual need.

Comment: I often cycle both ways in daily use (for instance in .tex documents and comment blocks), and have found the vim equivalent of 'ctrl' + 'arrowkeys' ('v' + 'w' or 'b'). But one (small) thing that makes vim better is that I can use 'iw' when cycling forwards (like starting with 'ctrl' + 'd' in sublime). So I wondered whether there existed an equivalently neat way to go backwards without going to the end of the word first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for `viwo` + `b` + `b` + `b`

Comment: Explanation:

viw => Select the current word;
o => Move the cursor to the other end of the selected word;
b => Move the cursor one word backward.