# Uppercase vs lowercase word motion commands

Tags: vim

Is there any difference between <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd>?

The game [vim adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/) has you pick up an uppercase <kbd>B</kbd> in order to skip over a rock on an exclamation point, i.e.:

```
Remember: 
wordsXare
not WORDSX!
```

The two 'X's represent a treasure chest and rock respectively. In order to skip over the rock, one has to use the uppercase <kbd>B</kbd> rather than the lowercase <kbd>b</kbd>. Then in usr_03.txt, section 03.1, it talks about the uppercase word motion commands.

```
   It is also possible to move by white-space separated WORDs.  This is not a
word in the normal sense, that's why the uppercase is used.  The commands for
moving by WORDs are also uppercase, as this figure shows:

           ge      b      w             e
           <-     <-   --->                   --->
    This is-a line, with special/separated/words (and some more). ~
       <----- <-----   -------------------->          ----->
         gE      B           W           E

With this mix of lowercase and uppercase commands, you can quickly move
forward and backward through a paragraph.
```

But when I do the `:help W` command, it gives me this:

```
4. Word motions                        word-motions

   or                  <S-Right> w
w           [count] words forward.  |exclusive| motion.

   or                  <C-Right> W
W           [count] WORDS forward.  |exclusive| motion.
```

There doesn't seem to be any difference. I'm using Vim 7.4.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931032/vim-word-vs-word

Answer (score 35):

This basically comes down to what vi considers to be a 'word'.

Here's a piece of text but navigated using uppercase W,B etc:

[image]

and here's the same text navigated using lowercase w,b etc:

[image]

Basically a 'WORD' is surrounded by whitespace whereas a 'word' can be surrounded and include certain characters such as - or ' etc.