# How to search for WORD (not word) under the cursor?

Tags: vim

How do I search for the `WORD` under the cursor? I know that `*` will find the `word` under the cursor, but I want to search for the `WORD`. That is, the text that is highlighted when I do `viW`.

Comment: @ladislas `WORD` and `word` have a very distinctive meaning in vim. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931032/vim-word-vs-word

Comment: I learned something today :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a default key for that, but you can add a mapping like:

```
:nnoremap & "xyiW/<C-R>x<CR>
```

Then pressing <kbd>&</kbd> would do the trick.

You might want to check [vim-visualstar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2944), this plugin makes <kbd>*</kbd> work with whatever you have selected.

Comment: A visual star is a great plugin to have (one of the first I install). See [Vim Awesome](http://vimawesome.com/?q=visual%20star) for some plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your own mapping for that:

```
:nnoremap & /<C-r>='\V\S\@<!' . escape(expand('<cWORD>'), '\') . '\S\@!'<CR><CR>
```

This uses `<cWORD>` to get the text (without clobbering a register), and ensures a full match by asserting that there's only whitespace before and after the match.