# how to select inside spaces in vim

Tags: vim

I have a shell script with the content

```
curl http://some-url.com -H "Content-Type: text/csv charset=UTF-8"
```

opened in vim. The cursor sits on the 's' in csv, and I want to replace text/csv by application/xml. How do I do that with the least number of key strokes? I tried "ciw", but that replaces only 'csv', not 'text/csv' Also "ci "  (with a space in the end) doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need `ciW`

Comment: awesome, thanks. For completeness, what does the capital W mean? What's the respective :help search term? Also, if you make it an answer I mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is `ciW`

The `W` stands for WORD (instead of `w` for word)

There is a question discussing the details here: [Vim: word vs WORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931032/vim-word-vs-word)