# Customize word boundaries of Option-Delete (and other word related shortcuts) in macOS?

Tags: macos, text, keyboard-shortcuts, textselection

Is it possible to change the behavior of ⌥⌫ (option+delete) to include certain characters, like a period, as a word boundary?

For example, in `some.variable`, I would like ⌥⌫ to delete up to the period but it currently deletes the entire string. The screencast below shows the behavior using ⌥⇧←.

[Screencast GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTdRE.gif)

Comment: You are the only person on the internet who has asked this question, and I am heartbroken that you've not had a response.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked high and low for a solution to this issue since the Cocoa-era, as far as I can tell there isn't a way to customize the "Option-Delete" word-delimiter (word-boundary) list. In addition to my own experiments, I'm basing this conclusion largely on the enormous number of MacOS keybinding modifications that can be found at the following 3 URLs (from oldest to most recently updated):

1. [Customizing the Cocoa Text System (circa 2006)](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/Site/cocoa-text.html)
2. [DefaultKeybinding.dict (circa 2016, some info previously at the URL "lri.me")](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220060333/http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html)
3. [Keybindings -- BrettTerpstra.com (last updated 2018)](https://brettterpstra.com/projects/keybindings/)

AFAIK, word-boundaries on MacOS default to whitespace and can't be changed. [This conclusion is invalid if there have been recent radical changes to MacOS text-input system].

It's no secret that many of the MacOS keyboard shortcuts are based upon eMacs-style 'keyboard-chording', as opposed to Vim-style 'modal-editing'. Indeed much of the Keybinding work cited above deals with remapping these chords. Vim of course is well-known for having a customizable delimiter list, it's the basis for differential word-movements between (for example) `w`, `W` and `b` and `B` (see [vimhelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/usr_03.txt.html#03.1)).

There have been a few extensions that have tried to bring 'Vim-style' editing to the MacOS, one of which  is Karabiner. Karabiner (now re-written/updated to [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)) used to have a mode called "Ubiquitous_Vim". However without an OS-level 'hook' personal tests indicate that (for example) moving backwards via `b` and `B` works identically (i.e. there's no difference between a Vim `word` and a Vim `WORD`, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22931032/7270649)).

While I'm unable to find a way to modify the MacOS default 'word-boundary' list, if Vim-style editing does appeal to you, then you might try installing a project such as [Vim-Anywhere](https://github.com/cknadler/vim-anywhere), which enables you to 1. use a MacOS keyboard shortcut to open a Vim window whenever you need to enter text, and 2. will automatically copy your text to the MacOS System Clipboard when you close the Vim window. See this OSTechNix article: ["How To Use Vim Editor To Input Text Anywhere"](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-use-vim-editor-to-input-text-anywhere/) for more information.